# jquery dialog resize the window down and a button disapear

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog created with a scroller in text and two buttons. The problem is when I resize the window down one button dissapear and then you have to close window and reopened it to see it again.

```js
// Public Domain
// Feel free to use any of the JavaScript, HTML, and CSS for any commercial or private projects. No attribution required.
// I'm not responsible if you blow anything up with this code (or anything else you could possibly do with this code).

$().ready(function() { // When the document is ready run the code inside the brackets.
  $("button").button(); // Makes the button fancy (ie. jquery-ui styled)
  $("#dialog").dialog({ // Set the settings for the jquery-ui dialog here.
    autoOpen: false, // Don't open the dialog instantly. Let an event such as a button press open it. Optional.
    position: {
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: "#constrained_div"
    } // Set the position to center of the div.
  }).parent().resizable({ // Settings that will execute when resized.
    containment: "#constrained_div" // Constrains the resizing to the div.
  }).draggable({ // Settings that execute when the dialog is dragged. If parent isn't used the text content will have dragging enabled.
    containment: "#constrained_div", // The element the dialog is constrained to.
    opacity: 0.70 // Fancy opacity. Optional.
  });

  $("#button").click(function() { // When our fancy button is pressed the stuff inside the brackets will be executed.
    $("#dialog").dialog("open"); // Opens the dialog.
  });
});
```

```css
/* We include the jquery-ui.css here to make sure it's used. */

@import "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
 #constrained_div {
  /* NOTICE avoid using margins since they screw up the true constraining div. */
  /* margin: 20px; */
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
}
#dialog {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="constrained_div">
    <div id="dialog" title="I'm the dialog!">Yay!hfherthertherth rtherthertherthertherthert therthrth rth erthertherther rtherthertherthertherthert therthrth rth erthertherther rtherthertherthertherthert therthrth rth erthertherther
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Click me">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Click mee">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

```
$().ready(function() { 
    $("button").button();
    $("#dialog").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: "#constrained_div"}
    }).parent().resizable({ 
        containment: "#constrained_div" 
    }).draggable({ 
        containment: "#constrained_div", 
        opacity: 0.70 // Fancy opacity. Optional.
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open"); // Opens the dialog.
    });
});
```

Any idea would be fantastic

Comment: Then align the buttons side by side?

Comment: Then align one on top of the other, how it should be acording to code. But as far as how to align them, why when you scroll down the $("#dialog") it's getting bigger but under the #constrained_div¿?

Comment: any idea how to fix it?